# Modify list data in single line using JDK8

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

In Java we can modify a `List` as below

```
for (Customer cust : customers) {
    cust.setAge(15);
    cust.setName("Customer1");
    cust.setAddress("Address1");
}
```

Using above code, it is possible to modify multiple attributes with one  loop.

In JDK8, it is possible to update list data with a `forEach` like :

```
customers.forEach(cust -> cust.setAge(15));
```

But I want to modify multiple attributes using java 8. How can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use a block for the lambda:

```
customers.forEach(cust -> {
    cust.setAge(15);
    cust.setName("Customer1");
    cust.setAddress("Address1");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using braces. Like,

```
customers.forEach(cust -> {
        cust.setAge(15); 
        cust.setName("Customer1"); 
        cust.setAddress("Address1");
});
```